# Excel get different cell value base on another cell value

Tags: excel

[image: enter image description]

As in the pic, I hope to get =('Working sheet'!**B26**) base on the cell value of age. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
=INDIRECT("'Working sheet'!B"&B2)
```